# Slow loading of Json data in iphone

Tags: iphone

Greetings of the day.

I am having table view where JSON data having text,distance and image is loading very slowly in cells,as i am scrolling down app is getting heavy... but i had seen in some apps that irrespective of image data.... text and distance has been loaded earlier and by activity indicator they are showing that image is loading.

I am not getting how to scroll faster in table view irrespective of image data.

thanx in advance

Software Developer

Comment: What JSON parser are you using?

Comment: thanx for the replying...that had been solved.Actually we were using Json parser only and exactly dont know what are u trying to ask me ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read [this Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7) about loading table view cells. I also am loading a UITableView from JSON web data, but what was really slow was the handling and loading of the table cell objects themselves.

It scrolled noticeably faster once I worked in the Apple-recommended cell handling code.

Comment: +1. I can almost guarantee the OP isn't using the cell caching mechanism built into UITableView.